# Octave imread bmp file

Tags: matlab, octave, bmp, imread

I need to read a file `myFile.bmp` in Octave but it doesn't work.

I have:

- Ubuntu 15.04
- Ocatve 3.8.2
- ImageMagick 8:6.8.9.9-5

When I run `imread('myFile.bmp')`, I get this:

```
octave:10> imread ("myFile.bmp")
error: imread: invalid image file: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/octave/3.8.2/oct/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/__magick_read__.oct: failed to load: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/octave/3.8.2/oct/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/__magick_read__.oct: undefined symbol: _ZN6Magick5ColorC1Ehhh
error: called from:
error:   /usr/share/octave/3.8.2/m/image/private/__imread__.m at line 181, column 7
error:   /usr/share/octave/3.8.2/m/image/private/imageIO.m at line 66, column 26
error:   /usr/share/octave/3.8.2/m/image/imread.m at line 107, column 30
```

When I run `imread('myFile.bmp', 'Format', 'bmp')`, I get the same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you installed everything from the Ubuntu repositories, then you are probably affected by an Ubuntu packaging issue.  It was described in [comment #6 of Ubuntu bug #1372202](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/octave/+bug/1372202/comments/6).

Since Ubuntu 15.04 has already reached [end of life](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/octave/+bug/1372202/comments/14), they probably won't fix it.  You can:

1. upgrade Ubuntu
2. build Octave from source yourself